# how to read integers only from a file, and ignore all spaces, so the output will be a table or list

Tags: python, file, analytics

many thanks

the reason I asked this question is that I want to analyse a table which I pulled out from a network switch, I only need to analyse the number;
but there are a few difficulties, please see the table I pulled out as below
1, the table contains random number of spaces between numbers and string, some are 5, and some are 12;
2, I only need to analyze the number or integer, I want to eliminate the strings,
3, its better to save this into 2-dimensional list,

I searched my question in this website, and tried a bit of functions people mentioned, like replace, split, and also tried a couple of lib like Anacoda; also tried different ideas, like replace space with , or read from .csv instead of .txt, or read only numbers, but none of them are working; I am still a new in programming, so definitely need to think about more, and definitely need people's help thanks

this is my current code to read the data, but can not analyze it

lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open ('result.txt')]

```
Port        Align-Err     FCS-Err    Xmit-Err     Rcv-Err  UnderSize  OutDiscards 
Gi1/0/1             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/2             0           0           0           0          0          443 
Gi1/0/3             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/4             0          80           0          86          0         4029 
Gi1/0/5             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/6             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/7             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/8             0           0           0           0          0          626 
Gi1/0/9             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/10            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/11            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/12            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/13            0           0           0           0          0          626 
Gi1/0/14            0           0           0           0          0          626 
Gi1/0/15            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/16            0           0           0           0          0          626 
Gi1/0/17            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/18            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/19            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/20            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/21            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/22            0           0           0           0          0           20 
Gi1/0/23            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/24            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/25            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/26            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/27            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/28            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/29            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/30            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/31            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/32            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/33            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/34            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/35            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/36            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/37            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/38            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/39            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/40            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/41            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/42            0           0           0           0          0           33 
Gi1/0/43            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/44            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/45            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/46            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/47            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/0/48            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi1/1/1             0           0           0           0          0          462 
Gi1/1/2             0           0           0           0          0          623 
Gi1/1/3             0           0           0           0          0           62 
Gi1/1/4             0           0           0           0          0           78 
Gi2/0/1             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/2             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/3             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/4             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/5             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/6             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/7             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/8             0           0           0           0          0          629 
Gi2/0/9             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/10            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/11            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/12            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/13            0           0           0           0          0          628 
Gi2/0/14            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/15            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/16            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/17            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/18            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/19            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/20            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/21            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/22            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/23            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/24            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/25            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/26            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/27            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/28            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/29            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/30            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/31            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/32            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/33            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/34            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/35            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/36            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/37            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/38            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/39            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/40            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/41            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/42            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/43            0           0           0           0          0          148 
Gi2/0/44            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/45            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/46            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/47            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/0/48            0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/1/1             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/1/2             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/1/3             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Gi2/1/4             0           0           0           0          0            0 
Po2                 0           0           0           0          0            0 
Po11                0           0           0           0          0            0 
Po12                0           0           0           0          0          181 
Po13                0           0           0           0          0            0 
Po14                0           0           0           0          0            0 
Po20                0           0           0           0          0            0 
Po21                0           0           0           0          0          462 
Po22                0           0           0           0          0          623 
Po23                0           0           0           0          0           62 
Po24                0           0           0           0          0           78 
Po25                0           0           0           0          0          443
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: I searched my question in this website, and tried a bit of functions people mentioned, like replace, split, and also tried a couple of lib like Anacoda; also tried different ideas, like replace space with , or read from .csv instead of .txt, or read only numbers, but none of them are working; I am still a new in programming, so definitely need to think about more, and definitely need people's help thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
with open('data', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

content = content.replace("\n", "").split(" ")
content = [content[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(content), 7)]
print content
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work as we want, add a lot of empty element in each lists